# CSS selector - first match in DOM

Tags: css, selector

I have a CSS selector: `span[data-update="status"]`

This selector retrieves between 0 and N spans in a page.

I want to modify this selector so it selects the span higher in the DOM.

All of these spans belong to TRs which belong to a single table, and I want to select the span which is highest in the table, or earliest in the DOM.

Answer (score 3):

CSS can not do that. However your language of choice will return an array with which you can then index the first element.

```
let element = document.querySelector("span[data-update=\"status\"]"); 

// or fetch the entire nodelist, and manually select the first element

let selection = document.querySelectorAll("span[data-update=\"status\"]");
let firstElement = selection[0];
```

JavaScript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList
Java: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/NodeList.html

Comment: I think you meant document.querySelectorAll

Comment: Yes, will fix now

Comment: Simply use `querySelector` and you're done. It is meant for exactly this reason. Big fan of answers that actually address the OP's initial questions - "CSS can not do this". Maybe add some more details about css, e.g. first-of-type and similar selectors.

Comment: @Christoph I provide a CSS version too :)

Comment: @Meghan Saying _CSS can not do that_ is not entirely correct, as it very well can.

Comment: @LGSon this is true for a very specific case only. I explain in a comment to your answer.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to select the span which is highest in the table, or earliest
>   in the DOM

Javascript

For that you can use [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), which will return the first match only, instead of `querySelectorAll`, which will return a lot more than needed, and would be less performant since you don't want all occurrences.

As you state these *spans* are in *table rows*, adding `table tr` to your initial selector will narrow down the search span so it only looks inside a `table` and its `tr`'s for the `span[data-update="status"]`.

```
var first_match = document.querySelector('table tr span[data-update="status"]');
```

---

CSS only

CSS can tackle this problem for specific cases, e.g. if your markup is relatively static and guarantees that the first `span[data-update="status"]` is always in the first `tr`. In these cases you can use a CSS rule to set its style.

It will fail for more generic cases, e.g. if you don't know under which `tr` your `span[data-update="status"]` occurs for the first time or you have no definite knowledge of the exact nesting of your table content or different levels of nesting. This is often the case with dynamically generated content.

```css
table:first-of-type tr:first-child span[data-update="status"]:first-of-type {
  color: red;
}


/*  for styling of this demo only  */
body > div ~ div { margin-top: 20px; }
table td { border: 1px dotted gray; }
```

```html
<div>TABLE 1</div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <h3></h3>
      <span data-update="status"> SOME TEXT </span>
      <span data-update="status"> SOME TEXT </span>
      <span data-update="status"> SOME TEXT </span>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <h3></h3>
      <span data-update="status"> SOME TEXT </span>
      <span data-update="status"> SOME TEXT </span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <h3></h3>
      <span data-update="status"> SOME TEXT </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div>TABLE 2</div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <h3></h3>
      <span data-update="status"> SOME TEXT </span>
      <span data-update="status"> SOME TEXT </span>
      <span data-update="status"> SOME TEXT </span>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <h3></h3>
      <span data-update="status"> SOME TEXT </span>
      <span data-update="status"> SOME TEXT </span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <h3></h3>
      <span data-update="status"> SOME TEXT </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Your css covers only one very specific case: You are assuming that `span[data-update="status"]` occurs within the first `tr`, which actually might not be the case. Second problem: You are assuming knowledge of the nesting (which seems to be a fair guess in the OPs example)! The spans you are looking for might in reality be nested further down and/or on different levels within the `tr`s thus also breaking this specific selector. Still a good effort from you pointing out, that CSS has some capabilities of tackling this problem for certain edge cases.

Comment: @Christoph Thanks ... and of course I assume all that, as there is no code available to set it up against, still, it proves that in many cases it can still work, and that is what I wanted to show. I also clearly stated the logic behind the chosen selector, and that it can fail.

Answer (score 0):

```
Element.querySelector('CSSselector')
```

... does exactly this. Note `Element` has to be a DOM element or `document` itself.

If using jQuery use either `$(parentToSearch)[0].querySelector('CSSselector')` or `$('CSSselector', parentToSearch).first()`

This can also be achieved with a pure CSS solution if the relation between the targeted spans and the subsequent siblings holding them (`<tr>`s) is the same, by styling all with `tr selector` and than negating the styling for all but first with `tr ~ tr selector`. Cumbersome and with limited applicability, but possible.

Comment: depends on the OP's expression "higher". This query selects the "first" element in the DOM.

Comment: @Christoph But further down he specifies it is "higher" in table.

Comment: Yes, saw that after writing my comment. Though this is js and not css, this is a way to solve the problem.